# Etymology of the word sanhedrin

Tags: etymology, beit-din-court, maseches-sanhedrin

What is the root and source of the term "sanhedrin," the name of the Jewish high court and of a tractate in the Talmud?

As far as I know, it is not from scripture.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85190

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I too was always bothered as to the origins of this word, until I saw the following Midrash Lekach Tov on Parshas Beha'aloscha:
ומהו לשון סנהדרין, סין זה תורה שניתנה מהר סיני, הדרין שמהדרין התורה במדרשה ומיפים ומישרין הכתוב זה עם זה-"What is the meaning of the term 'Sanhedrin'? 'Sin' refers to the Torah which was given from Mount 'Sin'ai, 'hadrin': since they beautify (מהדרין) the Torah in its extrapolation, and make better and straighten out that which is written, one (part) with another."

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and many thanks for this well-sourced aggadic answer! I hope to see you around the site. Please consider [registering](/users/signup-unregistered) your account; that will [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) more site features.

Answer (score 12):

From [TheSanhedrin.org](http://www.thesanhedrin.org/en/index.php?title=The_Re-established_Jewish_Sanhedrin):

> Etymologically, Sanhedrin is a late Hebrew representation of the Greek word synedrion συνέδριον meaning "sitting together" as a legislative assembly or Senate.

Answer (score 11):

[Jastrow](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/) supports Yishai's [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52929/5323), that "סנהדרין" derives from the Greek συνέδριον:

> ‎
>
> ### ‫סַנְהֶדְרִין,‬ ‫סַנְהֶדְרֵי‬
>
> [f.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feminine#English)  (also [*pl.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plural#English)) ([**συνέδριον**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%85%CE%BD%CE%AD%CE%B4%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%BD)) [***Sanhedrin***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanhedrin), the supreme council of the Jews; **ס‫'‬ גדולה** *the Great S.*, consisting of seventy-one members; **ס‫'‬ קטנה** *the Small S.*, a judicial court of twenty-three.  [Snh. I, 6.](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=2b&format=text) Ib. ראויה לס‫'‬ fit to be a seat of the S. [Macc. I, 10](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=7&format=text) ס‫'‬ נוהגת בארץ וכ‫'‬ the S. may exercise its functions in Palestine and outside.  Ib. ס‫'‬ ההורגת וכ‫'‬ a S. that executes capital punishment (more than) once in seven years.  [Ib. 9](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=6b&format=text) (ref. to [Deut. XVII, 6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0517.htm#6)) שלא תהא ס‫'‬ שומעת וכ‫'‬ this intimates that the S. must not hear the testimony from the mouth of an interpreter.  [Snh. 63a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=63&format=text) לס‫'‬ שהרגו וכ‫'‬ that a S. which puts a person to death must not taste food during the entire day of execution; [a. v. fr.](http://marker.to/G5NJpr) - *Pl.* **‫סַנְהֶדְ‬רָאוֹת‫,‬ ‫סַנְהֶדְ‬רָיוֹת‫,‬ ‫סַ‬נֶּ‫דְ‬רָ‫'‬**.  [Ib. I, 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=2&format=text) אין עושין ס‫'‬ לשבטים וכ‫'‬ supreme courts for tribes (provincial courts, Small Sanhedrin) can be instituted only by decree of the court of seventy-one; [Sifra K'dosh. ch. VIII, Par. 10](http://marker.to/YCVYOm) סנדריות של ישראל; [Yalk. Lev. 619](http://marker.to/0E5Ihh) סנהד‫'‬ של שבטים, opp. ס‫'‬ גדולה.  [Snh. 16b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=16b&format=text) סנדראות (also in Chald. diction); a. fr. - [***Sanhedrin***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanhedrin_%28tractate%29), name of a treatise, of the [Order of N'ziḳin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nezikin), of Mishnah, Tosefta and Talmud Babli a. Y'rushalmi.
>
> ### ‫סַנְדְּרִי,‬ ‫סַנְהֶדְרִין,‬ ‫סַנְהֶדְרִי‬
>
> [ch.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chaldaic#Proper_noun) same.  [Targ. Y. II Num. XXV, 4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51465&st=&pgnum=244).  [Targ. Y. I ib. 7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39745&st=&pgnum=306).  [Targ. I Chr. XVIII, 17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35985&st=&pgnum=51); a. fr. - [Snh. 16a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=16&format=text); a. fr. - *Pl.* **‫סַנְדַּרְיָיתָא,‬ ‫סַנְהֶדְ‬רְיָיתָא**.  [Targ. Y. I Lev. XXIV, 12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51466&st=&pgnum=301).  [Targ. Y. I Num. IX, 8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39745&st=&pgnum=94); a. fr.

As user6591 mentioned in [his answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52933/5323), the word is used in [Mishnayos Sanhedrin, 1:6](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.1.6) as "סנהדרי." Tiferes Yisrael, there ([#43](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37945&st=&pgnum=379)) writes that this is the Latin (לאטיין) word for it. He also says that the rabbis of the Mishna chose to use this word, because it (is נוטרריקון) stands for "שונא הדרת דין."

The actual words of the Maharil are found in the Likutei Maharil #6 אמר דלכך נקראו סנהדרין, מפני ששונאין הדרת פנים בדין, נוטריקון שלו כך. This roughly translates as they do not show favoritism while judging.

Comment: In all likelihood they got it from Jastrow...

Comment: @DoubleAA You're right, though quick scan of their site does not show that.

Comment: I have wondered for many years why the term Sanhedrin was favoured despite its non Jewish derivation over the term זקנים which is biblical. Any ideas?

Comment: @Yoni Why doesn't the מהרי"ל cover that? ...it stands for שונא הדרת דין.

Comment: Ok, I replaced the .png with typed text. If you don't like this, feel free to revert. If you only want to keep some of the Jastrow entry, you can now edit as you please.

Comment: @Fred Thanks. I kinda liked the look of the dictionary entry, but I appreciate why you thought this is better.

Comment: The Mahraril sounds more like a [backronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) than the original source for why the Greek word was chosen over the original Hebrew.

Answer (score 8):

In maseches Sanhedrin chapter one, mishna 6, the word is presented as sanhedrei. The Tiferes Yisroel #43 quotes the Aruch who writes this is the Latin version of the name. He also quotes the Maharil as saying Chazzal chose this word because in notrikin it stands for Sonei Hadras Din.

The actual words of the Maharil are found in the Likutei Maharil #6 אמר דלכך נקראו סנהדרין, מפני ששונאין הדרת פנים בדין, נוטריקון שלו כך. This roughly translates as they do not show favoritism while judging.

Comment: Do you mind if I scavenge the information from your answer, and put it into mine? ....I think it's the best answer on the page, honestly, and the information in here does not deserve to live on the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Shokhet sounds like a Torah attitude. Go for it:)

Comment: Done, thanks :) ....how would you translate "שונא הדרת דין"?

Comment: @Shokhet lol! I was gonna wish you good luck with that one:) I think it means hating to turn away justice, meaning they are willing to stand up for what's right, but i wasn't sure so i didn't translate it.

Comment: I guess I'll hold off on putting in a translation until one of us is sure. It sounds good, but I'm not either sure.

Comment: @Shokhet maybe I'll try skimming the maharil, see maybe he explains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20498/discussion-between-user6591-and-shokhet).

Answer (score 7):

Other answers have already noted that this comes from the Greek *συνέδριον* ("[synedrion](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synedrion)"). I'll add more detail: That word comes from the Greek  *σύνεδρος* ("sitting together"), from *σύν* ("with", also found in e.g. English *synergy* and *synchronize*) and *ἕδρα* ("seat", also found in English *cathedral* and distantly related to English *sit*).

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! ....is synedrion etymologically related to "synod" (another word I [learned on-site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45251/5323))?

Comment: @Shokhet, same _syn_ from _σύν_, but the rest is different.