# Use of Greek in the Sanhedrin

Tags: greek

Did the Sanhedrin ever use Greek as a main or auxiliary language during the Second Temple period? I ask because Sanhedrin is a Greek word and many Jews had Greek names so it stands to reason that the Greek language might have been used in the Sanhedrin as either a primary or auxiliary language.

Comment: The people spoke Aramaic in everyday matters.  Why would the Sanhedrin use Greek?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi other than the fact that the Sanhedrin had to know 70 languages, there are multiple sources that show that many people spoke Greek at the time. One of the strongest points is that Aquilas the convert wrote a Greek targum on behalf of R' Eliezer and R' Yehoshua, and there are sources that those two and other sages knew and spoke Greek. It was not their main language, but it was certainly used post-2nd Temple. The OP's question is, however, whether it was also in use prior to the destruction.

Comment: See the first two chapters of Saul Leiberman’s ‘Greek in Jewish Palestine’.

Comment: Not an answer, just strengthening the question: [Mishna Shekalim 3:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Shekalim.3.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94556/13811